SSL Certificate Error While Downloading Packages from GitHub with cURL Body
I'm encountering an SSL certificate error while trying to download Laravel packages using Composer. Here’s the error message I receive:
SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'codeload.github.com'
Failed to download laravel/breeze from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/laravel/breeze/legacy.zip


I'm using Composer to manage my Laravel project dependencies.
The issue arises during the syncing process of various Laravel packages, such as laravel/breeze, league/flysystem, and nette/schema.
The error occurs consistently for multiple packages.

Steps Taken :

Verified that the URLs in my configuration are correct.
Updated cURL and OpenSSL to their latest versions.
Attempted to disable SSL verification using the -k option, but this is not a recommended solution for production.

How can I fix this problem :

Has anyone experienced similar issues?
What steps can I take to resolve this SSL certificate validation problem?
Are there any best practices for handling SSL errors in Composer or cURL?

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Which PHP version are you using?

When I enter https://codeload.github.com/laravel/breeze/legacy.zip in my browser, I get a 400: Invalid request. That's weird. I had never seen the codeload.github.com domain before. Are you using Composer in a non-standard way?

But my composer works like that.

My php version is 8.2.0

I just tried composer require laravel/breeze in a new directory with PHP 8.2.0 and Composer 2.7.2, and it worked. In the generated composer.lock, I see that the URL used to download breeze is https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/breeze/zipball/1446994ea5042e0b340e39f1e4629656de843058.

"My php version is 8.2.0" - please keep in mind that this version is pretty outdated

It will be possible to fix it in two different ways.

By Composer: Run the command in the terminal composer config -g secure-http false
Or Manually update cacert.pem from composer directory

After running 1st point you need to install the library and after that, you need to run again composer config -g secure-http true
